# How to make additional measure with 1 week ago calculation?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I've done this graph with revenue calculation for today and last week.
[image: Last day graph]
[image: Last week graph]

Parameter for swith:

```
Parameter = 
{
    ("Last week", NAMEOF('Order_dates'[Datetime]), 0),
    ("Last day", NAMEOF('Order_dates'[Time]), 1)
}
```

Measure for calculation (it's working right):

```
_revenue = 
VAR _today = TODAY()
VAR _last_day = 
CALCULATE(
    sum('Sells'[Revenue]),
    KEEPFILTERS(
        DATESINPERIOD(
            '_calendar'[Date],
            TODAY(), 
            -1, 
            DAY)
    )
)
VAR _last_week =
CALCULATE(
    sum('Sells'[Revenue]),
    KEEPFILTERS(
        DATESINPERIOD(
            '_calendar'[Date],
            TODAY(),
            -7,
            DAY)
    )
)
RETURN
SWITCH(
    TRUE(),
    ISINSCOPE('Order_dates'[Datetime]), _last_week,
    ISINSCOPE('Oreder_dates'[Time]), _last_day
)
```

Model:

[image: data model]

Calendar:

[image: Calendar]

I've tryed use relationship (Order_dates[Date], _calendar[prev_week_for_plot]), there's prev_week_for_plot is shifted dates b 7 days (check calendar, if you need).
I used that logic before in SQL-querys, there's it works.

But I still got wrong result.

```
_week_ago = 
VAR _today = TODAY()
VAR _time_shift = 7
VAR _last_day = 
CALCULATE(
    sum('Sells'[Revenue]),
    KEEPFILTERS(
        DATESINPERIOD(
            _calendar[prev_week_for_plot],
            TODAY() - _time_shift, 
            -1, 
            DAY)
    ),
    USERELATIONSHIP(Order_dates[Date], _calendar[prev_week_for_plot])
)
VAR _last_week =
CALCULATE(
    sum('Sells'[Revenue]),
    KEEPFILTERS(
        DATESINPERIOD(
            _calendar[prev_week_for_plot],
            TODAY() - _time_shift,
            -7,
            DAY)
    ),
    USERELATIONSHIP(Order_dates[Date], _calendar[prev_week_for_plot])
)
RETURN
SWITCH(
    TRUE(),
    ISINSCOPE('Order_dates'[Datetime]), _last_week,
    ISINSCOPE('Order_dates'[Time]), _last_day
)
```

With result:

[image]
[image]

I got right result with last-day calculation.

I have to shift last week's values to the right on the graph.

I

Answer (score 0):

I figure out, that I done wrong.
First I add next day/week dates to Order_dates.

Parameter:

```
Parameter = 
{
    ("Last week", NAMEOF(_calendar[Date]), 0),
    ("Last day", NAMEOF(_time[Time]), 1)
}
```

Corrected data model:
[image]

And correct USERELATIONSHIP and SWITCH in my measure:

```
_prev_day = 
VAR _today = TODAY()
VAR _time_shift = 0
VAR _last_day = 
CALCULATE(
    sum('Sells'[Revenue]),
    KEEPFILTERS(
        DATESINPERIOD(
            _calendar[Date],
            TODAY() - _time_shift, 
            -1, 
            DAY)
    ),
    USERELATIONSHIP(_calendar[Date], Order_dates[next_day_date])
)
VAR _last_week =
CALCULATE(
    sum('Sells'[Revenue]),
    KEEPFILTERS(
        DATESINPERIOD(
            _calendar[Date],
            TODAY() - _time_shift,
            -7,
            DAY)
    ),
    USERELATIONSHIP(_calendar[Date], Order_dates[next_day_date])
)
RETURN
SWITCH(
    TRUE(),
    ISINSCOPE(_calendar[Date]), _last_week,
    ISINSCOPE(_time[Time]), _last_day
)
```

Result:

[image]
[image]